Filling in NULL data in vector grid with values derived from Nearest neighbour cell values
I have created a grid with 5m x 5m cells which contains the summed values from a point file.
Within the grid I have NULL values (selected in Yellow) where there was no points within the cell, yet the surrounding cells do contain values. Red values are summed Cell Values from the Black point values.

How do I populate the null values where they are adjacent cells with a representative based on the surrounding cells?

Similar to creating a rainfall distribution map but my understanding is IDW is NOT suitable as Inverse distance weighted (IDW) interpolation explicitly makes the assumption that things that are close to one another are more alike than those that are farther apart. This data is not like that it is random.
The Blue circle is the areas and I would like to fill in using surrounding data. For example the 3x3 grid where the middle cell is NULL could take the values of the average of the nearest neighbors.
The Red Arrow in the screen shot after running the tool would remain NULL as the surrounding cells are also NULL.
I am tried to follow this QGIS tutorial (https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/training_manual/processing/interpolation.html) but the sorghum example file does not contain the attribute "Area Count". But the end result of the tutorial is what I would like to produce - A yield Map.

Just being devils advocate. You say you don't want to use interpolation as that make assumptions. You've suggested a mean from nearest neighbours but that falls over with large areas of nulls and you specifically mention that the data is "random". Why not fill null cells with random values instead? Using a plausible range? If everything else is random would you not be introducing bias to what were null cells that now have an influenced value from their neighbours (the mean)?

Hi Hornbydd, Firstly thank you for your comment and incite. Yes I believe this will work as long as all areas require null values to be not NULL. However, in this specific case the Blue areas needs to be not NULL and larger areas consecutive to remain as NULL. I solved my issue by running close gaps algorithm after converting the grid to a raster. Wider context to this problem data comes from harvest monitor counting total nuts picked up every 2 seconds. Specific tree location counts are not important it is the total change in nut density across the orchard is what I am trying to represent.
